# How to automatically detect change in a blockchain system?

Tags: database, blockchain

I was wondering ways to **automatically** detect change (tampered block) in a blockchain system. My first thought was to have a function to check for block validity. Now that can be triggered by the node on a timer, by a push of a button by the node, when new block is added etc. Is there any other way to validate a blockchain when there is actually a change? For example, when a 'hacker' tampered with a block, it triggers the function/script.

Another question, does a database have the functionality to detect change automatically? For example, does MySQL, MonggoDB, etc. have functionalities that can detect when a change is made and notify  an app that there was a change?

Comment: Blocks are validated as they are received... otherwise they are not accepted atall. Accepted blocks cannot be changed (or all further blocks rooted from them wouldn't be valid either), so don't need revalidated. This is kindof a main concept that makes blockchains effective. Yes most databases have methods to detect changes and notify apps - from Triggers all the way to Message Broker and SqlChangeNotification in .Net

Comment: Right, i understand that, but what i am asking if someone has the massive computational power to change a block (and all the blocks after that) in a blockchain, how would we, as a developer, handle that? @Milney

Comment: @FirdausIndrahirmaya - You cannot. That is called a 51% attack, and chains simply rely on having >51% of the hashpower in the hands of honest users. That's kindof the entire linchpin of the system...